# With PHP download full html with all files

Tags: php, download, html

When I download html code with php by using `file_get_contents`.
I get a part of what I need.

In a page some images and html tag's are created by JavaScrip.

On a chrome by pressing f12 I can find a link, but if I print out php downloaded html there is none. Is there a way to get everything as if it was view on a browser? Or save everything, like on a browser Save as...

Comment: You effectively need to run a browser to do that.  It's not enough to just scrape all the resources... some will have URLs generated programmatically.  Furthermore, there is no guarantee that you'll have a perfect snapshot.  Look at PhantomJS.

Comment: Agree with @Brad there. Especially if it's generated OTF. Maybe `cURL` could be a better way of achieving this?

Comment: @Darren cURL doesn't execute code.  You have the same problem there.

Comment: @Brad Ah! That explains that then!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `wget`

```
wget --page-requisites yourUrl
```

and use `exec` or `system` to invoke through php.